# Cartesian product with a set within a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to calculate cartesian product of two sets: $A = \{a, \{b, \emptyset \}\}$ and $B = \{\emptyset \}$. I am unsure, how this sould work: $$A \times B = \{ (a, \emptyset), (\{b, \emptyset \}, \emptyset) \}$$ or since $X \times \emptyset = \emptyset$: $$A \times B = \{ (a, \emptyset), \emptyset \}$$

Is either soultion correct?

Comment: One of them is. Yes. Apply the definitions. Slowly. Nothing more, but nothing less. If it helps, and it would, write $A$ as $\{a_1,a_2\}$ and $B$ as $\{y\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $X \times Y = \{ (x,y) : x \in X, y \in Y \}$.

Then let $A = \{a, \{b, \emptyset \}\}$ and $B = \{\emptyset \}$.

We have $a \in A$ and $\emptyset \in B$ so $(a,\emptyset) \in A \times B$.

We also have $\{b, \emptyset \} \in A$ and $\emptyset \in B$ so $(\{b, \emptyset \},\emptyset) \in A \times B$.

This means $A \times B = \{(a,\emptyset),(\{b, \emptyset \},\emptyset)\}$.

Notice that the second solution is impossible as it contains a non-pair.

Comment: In order to avoid overusing a specific symbol, it might have been helpful to rewrite your first line as $X\times Y = \{(x,y)~:~x\in X,y\in Y\}$ instead so that it is clear that the $a$ in the first line is not necessarily the $a$ in the second line.

Comment: Thanks that was a good idea; I never would have thought of that.